# Explain the use of CSS properties: -webkit-border-radius and border-radius

Tags: css

[image]   Why are values of 25px of -webkit-border-radius and border-radius in different positions?

```
table.cal{
    color: #064525c;
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 3px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: **25px 25px** 0 0;
    border-radius: 0 0 **25px 25px**;
}
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/ Basically the -webkit prefix is used before it is fully supported, which means it can be using an older syntax. In saying this, I just did a test using Firefox to write out the CSS for both of those and they were both in the same order, so that's a bit odd. Maybe check in your browser inspector to see how they're rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm impressive courses advertised in the link embedded in your reply. I would take some after I gain the basic of HTML, CSS and Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Webkit is a engine for safari and Google chrome. but chrome use Blink engine instead of Webkit. That mean Blink can do the job of Webkit. And now Microsoft Edge is also support for Webkit. And Don't forget webkit engine was created by Apple for safari browser.

1. The meaning of -webkit- code in CSS is,
   This code is only works on browsers with an engine that supports webkit. for example Chrome,safari and Microsoft EDGE.
2. -webkit-border-radius: **25px 25px** 0 0;
   This code is only works on browsers with an engine that supports webkit.
3. border-radius: 0 0 **25px 25px**;
   This code works on any browser.